# How can I embed a visual brush at the end of a multi-line TextBlock?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `LinkButton` template for external hyperlinks. Such a `LinkButton` should have a little icon at the end (a `VisualBrush`, not an image file) of its text to inform the user that clicking this link will open a browser window and open some external website, like in this example:

[image: example hyperlink with inline icon]

<sup>(source: [this wikipedia article's reference section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_South_African_unrest#cite_note-1))</sup>

My current naive implementation of the style with the template:

```
<Style x:Key="LinkButtonExternalBaseStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Grid Name="grdLinkButtonExternal" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
            />
            <Rectangle
                Grid.Column="2"
                Name="imgExternalHyperlinkIcon"
                Style="{StaticResource RectangleExternalHyperlinkIconStyle}"
            />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Style>
```

(`RectangleExternalHyperlinkIconStyle` is a rectangle style having a `VisualBrush` as its `Fill`, representing the icon in question) along with:

```
<Button
    Command="{Binding OpenExternalHyperlinkCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding Gizmo.Hyperlink}"
    Style="{StaticResource LinkButtonExternal1Style}"
    Content="{Binding Gizmo.Hyperlink.AbsoluteUri}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
/>
```

results in:

[image: multi-line hyperlink with icon next to it]

where the image is always next to the (possibly multi-line) hyperlink and not inlined. For shorter links it looks fine:

[image: single-line hyperlink with icon next to it]

**So how can I achieve a multi-line hyperlink with an inline icon like in the example above?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having checked multiple stackoverflow posts and other google results, I stumbled upon `<InLineUIContainer>` and was able to solve this issue by "splitting" the `TextBlock` into multiple parts, binding the `Content` to a `Run` element and then *actually inlining* the icon:

```
<Style x:Key="LinkButtonExternalBaseStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
            <Run Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Rectangle
                    Name="imgExternalHyperlinkIcon"
                    Style="{StaticResource RectangleExternalHyperlinkIconStyle}"
                    Margin="3,0,0,0"
                />
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </TextBlock>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Style>
```

resulting in:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You would not even have to declare the `<InlineUIContainer>` explicitly. `<Run .../><Rectangle .../>` will also work.